# Does Tridion have an event which can be triggered when importing items via Content Porter

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, event-system

Does Tridion (2011 SP1) have an event which can be triggered when we are importing items via SDL Content Porter 2009 SP2? Currently we have a requirement to save release related information. For example: imported release name, imported date and so on.

Comment: did you try the rollback feature of the Content Porter where all this information related to previous imports

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. we cannot just rollback for some cases.Actually we want to create an audit trail for tracking assets within releases as content gets migrated from a lower source environment to a higher target environment during the content life-cycle. it will create a link between the different versions of the assets across different environments; and ensure that the same version of code and content gets migrated from the source environment to all the subsequent target environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Content Porter imports an item, it executes a normal save. You can therefore use the standard Save events. In order to distinguish between Content Porter imports and other saves, it might make sense to have a dedicated User for Content Porter imports. Your events can then process Saves by this user accordingly.

Comment: thanks.It make sense we can monitor this event against operating user. now the new problem is where can I get the release related information(release name, version in source system), I need to think about the whole solution to find a mechanism to save those information in somewhere and import event handler can get that information.

Answer (score 2):

We are using following simple approach.

- Create component having release info (anyhow you need this info), and include component in you every package.
- Import date of that component on destination server can full-fill your second requirement.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.It is a good solution,however,it seems we need add new field on certain schema which is using by all existing components so that we can add those information into it? for your 2nd suggestion, can you please provide more detail how to find the import date?

Comment: When your explore folder you will see modified date in one of the column. Just saw more description in your question, i am using only one component to track the info, but looks like you wanted to have this information in all of the items? is my observation right?

Comment: Yes, we need to trace all the components in one release package in different environment.